# Change color on some characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I highlight the minutes (22) when displaying this time using Javascript/jQuery?
I want 22 to have a different color than 11 and 33.

11:22:33

Thank you!

Comment: I try to accept as much as I can but I got a lot of questions unanswered. How would the regex look like in this case?

Comment: Depends how brittle your time format is but I have added an example to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `<span>` tag around the minutes portion and use an appropriate style.

```
11:<span class="minutes">22</span>:33

.minutes
{
  color: #ff0000;    
}
```

As per your update, if you want to insert the spans using regexp you can do this

```
var x = "11:22:33";
var y = x.replace(/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/ ,"<span class='hours'>$1</span>:<span class='minutes'>$2</span>:<span class='seconds'>$3</span>");
alert(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a `<span>` and use CSS to change the color.

```
<span class="hrs">11</span>:<span class="mins">22</span>:<span class="secs">33</span>
```

Then, in your CSS:

```
.hrs {
  color: red;
}

.mins {
  color: blue;
}

.secs { 
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the time generated? If its just regular HTML, try this:

```
<style>
.hours
{
    color:red;
}    
.minutes
{
    color:green;
}
.seconds
{
    color:blue;
}
</style>

<span class='hours'>11</span>:<span class='minutes'>22</span>:<span class='seconds'>33</span>
```

Use CSS to apply the colors.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting time in this way (just a rough code)

```
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
document.write("<span class="minutes">minutes</span>");
```

Then using jquery you can change the color of minute as,

```
$(.minutes).css("color","Red");
```